# Popup Modal Dialog from Route Guard

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

From blog post [protecting routes using guards in angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html) we can pop a message when a user cannot access a route. :

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { CanDeactivateComponent } from './app/can-deactivate';

export class ConfirmDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanDeactivateComponent> {

  canDeactivate(target: CanDeactivateComponent) {
    if(target.hasChanges()){
        return window.confirm('Do you really want to cancel?');
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

I would like to show a modal dialog using [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) to allow the user to login.

I have managed to get some simple code loading the modal from the main app (eg not a child view from my `app.component.ts`), such as

```
showloginModal() {
  this.loginModal.show();
}
```

the modal is loaded from another HTML file with (I include the core login code with the selector app-login

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <app-login  #loginModal> </app-login>
</div>
```

*edit*
I have just had a look at [Angular2 DialogService – Exploring Bootstrap](https://long2know.com/2017/01/angular2-dialogservice-exploring-bootstrap-part-2/) and that looks like it does the job but it's for bootstrap4

Comment: are you planning to use it across all components?

Comment: from my route guard.

Comment: you cannot do it that way. instead you should handle it in the app.component

Comment: in simple terms, I need to pop a dialog from a service, I have just added this link that does it with bootstrap4 https://long2know.com/2017/01/angular2-dialogservice-exploring-bootstrap-part-2/ but not from a route guard. But I presume (note *presume*) that if it will work from a route guard it will work from a service)

Comment: another approach might be to use a global variable and display the dialog based on that.

Comment: yes. that is `ngbootstrap` you can use from route guard as shown in that link. what is the problem now?

Comment: wrong bootstrap version :) thanks for the input so far.

Comment: cool..... hope you got clarity

Comment: My project is on bootstrap 3 so that blog demo won't work, BUT I am going to move to bootstrap 4 and try the method in blog.

Comment: ok. lemme know if you need any help

Comment: here is my solution to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433195/angular-use-modal-dialog-in-candeactivate-guard-service-for-unsubmitted-changes

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) but you can with [@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap).

Example usage from a `Service`

```
this.dialogService.show("Logged Out","You are out of here");
```

Example usage from a `route guard`

```
async canActivate() {
  if (!this.auth.loggedIn()) {
    await this.loginDialogService.confirm();
    return this.auth.loggedIn();
  }
  return true;
}
```

Source code for the service.

**dialog.component.ts**

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons,NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent   {
    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal,public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
    public title: string;
    public message: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class DialogService {  
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  public show(title: string, message:string) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(DialogComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
    return modalRef.result;
  }
}
```

**dialog.component.html**

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{title}}</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.close()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  {{message}}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="activeModal.close()">Ok</button>
</div>
```

You also need to make it an `entryComponent` add

```
entryComponents: [DialogComponent,LoginDialogComponent]
```

to you `@NgModule`

Credit to [long2know](https://long2know.com/2017/01/angular2-dialogservice-exploring-bootstrap-part-2/) good blog to start with.

Comment: will it work with bootstrap 3.not worried abiut the css..but will the functionality work?

Comment: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap is for bootstrap 4, but  you could code something up for bs3

Comment: any other modal dialog that supports promise method..trying to use with can activate guard something similar to confirm of javascript?

Comment: Quick update from the future, if you're using Angular 9+ you don't need to add it to the `entryComponents` array because it is [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#the-entrycomponents-array).